# Angular 2 externalization (properties file)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, build, angular

What is the approved way of externalizing string constant in Angular 2 application, or in JavaScript application in general? I mean something like `.properties` file in Java, where backend connection attributes are stored.

As far as I know, JavaScript doesn't support reading from file in client end easily. My current solution is to use injectable service class, which stores key-value pairs as an object attributes. Then I just inject the service in other services which needs those values. Is this justifiable method, or does JavaScript/A2 provide some more uniform way to handle value injection?

Comment: There is something work-in-progress to be released "soon" by the Angular team.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the way to do is the right one.

You could bootstrap asynchronously after your request(s) complete(s). Here is a sample:

```
var app = platform(BROWSER_PROVIDERS)
  .application([BROWSER_APP_PROVIDERS, appProviders]);

var service = app.injector.get(ConfigService);

service.getConfig().flatMap((config) => {
  var configProvider = new Provider('config', { useValue: config });
  return app.bootstrap(appComponentType, [ companiesProvider ]);
}).toPromise();
```

See this question:

- [How to defer Main component's initialization of dependent components so that some promises may get resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36908849/how-to-defer-main-components-initialization-of-dependent-components-so-that-som/36908911#36908911)

I see another approach if you're able to update `index.html` page (the main entry point) on the server side. Here is a sample:

```
<script>
  var params = {"token": "@User.Token", "xxx": "@User.Yyy"};
  System.import('app/main').then((module) => {
    module.main(params);
  });
</script>
```

See this question:

- [How to pass parameters rendered from backend to angular2 bootstrap method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37611549/how-to-pass-parameters-rendered-from-backend-to-angular2-bootstrap-method/37611677#37611677)

You could also register an `APP_INITIALIZER` provider for this:

```
provide(APP_INITIALIZER, {
  useFactory: (service:ConfigService) => () => service.loadConfig(), 
  deps:[ConfigService, HTTP_PROVIDERS],
  multi: true}),
```

See this issue for more details:

- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9047

Comment: So much verbosity to implement the simplest of the tasks. Angular 2 code seems to be ultimately hard to maintain, I hope they will adapt convention over configuration approach over time

Comment: Yes, perhaps this will be easier in the future with tools like ng-constants that will tackle packaging...

Comment: What about using environment.ts?