# Synchronous blocking subscribe call to a custom ReplaySubject based observable

Tags: angular, observable, rxjs-observables

The view contains the element:

```
<div *ngIf="showMe">Hello</div>
```

When calling the component method:

```
downloadDemo(): void {
  this.download$ = this.downloadService.downloadUrlAsBlobWithProgressAndSaveInFile('assets/skypeforlinux-64.deb', 'demo')
  this.download$.subscribe((download: Download) => {
    this.showMe = true;
    console.log('Progress: ' + download.progress);
  })
}
```

the element shows in the view before all the `Progress` loggers. And that is how it should be. This HTTP based downloading works just fine.

However when calling the component method:

```
downloadSoundtrack(soundtrack: Soundtrack): void {
  const fileName: string = soundtrack.name + '.' + MIDI_FILE_SUFFIX;
  const progress$: Observable<ProgressTask<Uint8Array>> = this.midiService.progressiveCreateSoundtrackMidi(soundtrack);
  this.download$ = this.downloadService.downloadObservableDataAsBlobWithProgressAndSaveInFile(progress$, fileName);
  this.download$.subscribe((download: Download) => {
    this.showMe = true;
    console.log('Progress: ' + download.progress);
  })
}
```

the element shows in the view last after all the `Progress` loggers. It is not how it should be. This custom `ReplaySubject` based observable is not working as expected. Indeed, the element should show before and not after all the `Progress` loggers.

I wanted to see if one subscribe call was blocking.

So I changed the two methods to:

```
downloadSoundtrack(soundtrack: Soundtrack): void {
  const fileName: string = soundtrack.name + '.' + MIDI_FILE_SUFFIX;
  const progress$: Observable<ProgressTask<Uint8Array>> = this.midiService.progressiveCreateSoundtrackMidi(soundtrack);
  this.download$ = this.downloadService.downloadObservableDataAsBlobWithProgressAndSaveInFile(progress$, fileName);
  this.showMe = true;
  this.download$.subscribe((download: Download) => {
    console.log('Progress: ' + download.progress);
  });
  console.log('Call done');
}

downloadDemo(): void {
  this.download$ = this.downloadService.downloadUrlAsBlobWithProgressAndSaveInFile('assets/skypeforlinux-64.deb', 'demo')
  this.showMe = true;
  this.download$.subscribe((download: Download) => {
    console.log('Progress: ' + download.progress);
  });
  console.log('Call done');
}
```

Here are the loggers when calling the `downloadDemo()` method:

```
Progress: 0
Call done
Progress: 0
Progress: 0
Progress: 2
Progress: 3
```

We can see the `subscribe()` call is non blocking.

Here are the loggers when calling the `downloadSoundtrack()` method:

```
Progress: 96
Progress: 97
Progress: 100
Call done
```

We can see the `subscribe()` call is blocking.

Adding an explicit `this.detectChanges();` call made no difference:

```
downloadSoundtrack(soundtrack: Soundtrack): void {
  const fileName: string = soundtrack.name + '.' + MIDI_FILE_SUFFIX;
  const progress$: Observable<ProgressTask<Uint8Array>> = this.midiService.progressiveCreateSoundtrackMidi(soundtrack);
  this.download$ = this.downloadService.downloadObservableDataAsBlobWithProgressAndSaveInFile(progress$, fileName);
  this.download$.subscribe((download: Download) => {
    this.showMe = true;
    this.detectChanges();
    console.log('Progress: ' + download.progress);
  })
}
```

It still showed after all the `Progress` loggers.

I have also tried some explicit  subscription in place of the `*ngIf="download$ | async as download"` in the template, but it did not help any:

```
downloadInProgress(soundtrack: Soundtrack): boolean {
  let inProgress: boolean = false;
  if (soundtrack.download) {
    if (soundtrack.download.progress > 0 && soundtrack.download.progress < 100) {
      inProgress = true;
    } else if (soundtrack.download.progress == 100) {
      console.log('complete');
      soundtrack.download = undefined;
    }
  }
  console.log('inProgress ' + inProgress);
  return inProgress;
}
```

The long running service:

```
public progressiveCreateSoundtrackMidi(soundtrack: Soundtrack): Observable<ProgressTask<Uint8Array>> {
  return Observable.create((progressTaskBis$: ReplaySubject<ProgressTask<Uint8Array>>) => {
    this.createSoundtrackMidi(soundtrack, progressTaskBis$);
    progressTaskBis$.complete();
    return { unsubscribe() { } };
  });
}

public createSoundtrackMidi(soundtrack: Soundtrack, progressTask$?: ReplaySubject<ProgressTask<Uint8Array>>): Uint8Array {
  const midi: Midi = new Midi();
  midi.name = soundtrack.name;
  midi.header.name = soundtrack.name;
  let noteIndex: number = 0;
  if (soundtrack.hasTracks()) {
    soundtrack.tracks.forEach((track: Track) => {
      const midiTrack: any = midi.addTrack();
      midiTrack.name = track.name;
      midiTrack.channel = track.channel;
      if (track.hasMeasures()) {
        let totalDurationInSeconds: number = 0;
        for (const measure of track.getSortedMeasures()) {
          if (measure.placedChords) {
            if (!this.notationService.isOnlyEndOfTrackChords(measure.placedChords)) {
              for (const placedChord of measure.placedChords) {
                if (!this.notationService.isEndOfTrackPlacedChord(placedChord)) {
                  const duration: string = placedChord.renderDuration();
                  const durationInSeconds: number = Tone.Time(duration).toSeconds();
                  const velocity: number = placedChord.velocity;
                  // const tempoInMicroSecondsPerBeat: number = this.beatsToMicroSeconds(1, measure.getTempo());
                  // const ticks: number = this.beatsToTicks(durationInBeats, DEFAULT_MIDI_PPQ, tempoInMicroSecondsPerBeat);
                  for (const note of placedChord.notes) {
                    if (!this.notationService.isEndOfTrackNote(note)) {
                      if (progressTask$) {
                        this.commonService.sleep(50);
                        progressTask$.next(this.downloadService.createProgressTask<Uint8Array>(soundtrack.getNbNotes(), noteIndex));
                      }
                      noteIndex++;
                      midiTrack.addNote({
                        midi: this.synthService.textToMidiNote(note.renderAbc()),
                        time: totalDurationInSeconds,
                        // ticks: ticks,
                        name: note.renderAbc(),
                        pitch: note.renderChroma(),
                        octave: note.renderOctave(),
                        velocity: velocity,
                        duration: durationInSeconds
                      });
                    }
                  }
                totalDurationInSeconds += durationInSeconds;
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    });
  }
  if (progressTask$) {
    progressTask$.next(this.downloadService.createProgressTask<Uint8Array>(soundtrack.getNbNotes(), soundtrack.getNbNotes(), midi.toArray()));
  }
  return midi.toArray();
}
```

There is a sleep call of 50ms slowing down the file creation, so as to give some ample time.

The implementation of the download service is based on [this article](https://nils-mehlhorn.de/posts/angular-file-download-progress)

I'm on Angular 9.1.0

Comment: You are binding your `*ngIf` to a simple method call and expect it to be refreshed automatically? That's what `Observables` are for.
Please add the code for `this.soundtracks` in your component, is that a plain array?

Comment: Yes it is an array `soundtracks!: Array<Soundtrack>;` I reckon the view should update on the changed member method return value though. Specially after an explicit call to detect the changes.

Comment: Concerning your update, this is what I meant in my first comment: Angular does not automatically binds conditions and templates, that's what Observables are for.

Comment: I posted another question relating to this one at https://stackoverflow.com/q/65060800/958373 with a stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-u3gz1t

Answer (score 1):

To keep things simple I would suggest to move to a more reactive state-driven approach where you could do something similar to the following:

1.

Change `soundtracks` from an array to a `public readonly soundtracks: Observable<Soundtrack[]> = this.soundtracksSubject.asObservable()` to enable your UI to register for changes. `this.soundtracksSubject` is then `private readonly soundtracksSubject: BehaviorSubject<Soundtrack[]> = new BehaviorSubject([]);` that then can be used to trigger observers of `soundtracks` to refresh. When you receive the HTTP response you then do not set `this.soundtracks = soundtracks;` but rather call `this.soundtracksSubject.next(soundtracks))`.

Also when doing the actual download (`soundtrack.download = download;`) instead of only changing your model after the change you have to call the subject again to propagate changes in your model to listeners:

```
const updatedSoundtracks: Soundtrack[] = this.soundtracksSubject.value.map(existingSoundtrack => existingSoundtrack);
const soundtrack: Soundtrack = updatedSoundtracks.find(existingSoundtrack => soundtrack.name === existingSoundtrack.name); // Or whatever identifies your soundtrack

if (soundtrack) {
    soundtrack.download = download;
    this.soundtracksSubject.next(updatedSoundtracks);
}
```

2. 

Change your UI from `<tr *ngFor="let soundtrack of soundtracks">` to `<tr *ngFor="let soundtrack of soundtracks | async">` to resolve the `Observable` to use it in your Angular component. This also means your component will register to changes on `soundtracks` and will get notified once somebody calls the subject/the observable.

`Observable` and `BehaviorSubject` are both RxJS concepts (`import {BehaviorSubject, Observable} from "rxjs/index";`) and are worthwhile to research because they make your life so much easier.