# How to read config file before Angular 2 app start?

Tags: angular

I need some configuration data from my json file before any component or servise is rendered by the Angular 2 framework. I have not found any good working solution to achieve that.

I am using Angular 2 RC6 working in the mixed mode with Angular 1 so I am using upgrade adapter to perform bootstraping.

Have you got any ideas to achieve what I need?

Comment: What about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39452451/2587435)

Comment: I am sorry, but not sure about your link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In "main.ts" file I used the jQuery "$.getJSON" function to load the config file and on callback I call the bootstrap funtion:

```
declare var $: any;
declare var configFile: string;

import './polyfills.ts';

import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';
import { AppModule } from './app';

if (environment.production) {
    enableProdMode();
    this.configFile = 'assets/config.prod.json';
} else {
    this.configFile = 'assets/config.json';
}

$.getJSON(this.configFile, (data) => {
    environment.config = data;

    platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
});
```

This way you can ensure bootstrapping is performed after your config data is fully loaded.

Comment: terrible idea.. first of all no jquery needed at all, better use service for that

Comment: @dontHaveName this code is running before Angular is bootstrapped, there are no services

Answer (score 2):

Check out this blog: https://www.cidean.com/blog/2019/initialize-data-before-angular-app-starts/

It uses `APP_INITIALIZER` to hook `AppConfigService` before app startup and fetch data. See the blog also for implementation of `AppConfigService`.

```
import { NgModule, APP_INITIALIZER } from '@angular/core';
import { AppConfigService } from './services/app-config.service';

export function appInit(appConfigService: AppConfigService) {
  return () => appConfigService.load();
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'ng-cli-universal' }),
  ],
  providers: [AppConfigService,
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: appInit,
      multi: true,
      deps: [AppConfigService]
    }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```