# Injecting dependencies inside the NgModule import section of an angular 2 app

Tags: angular, angular2-services, ngrx

I need to be able to inject and use a angular 2 service (called `SomeService` below) from the imports section of `NgModule`:

```
...
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(AppRoutes, {useHash: true}),
    HttpModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    NgbModule,
    StoreModule.provideStore({
        currentUserAccount: someFunction(currentUserAccountReducer, someService),
        authenticated: someFunction(authenticatedReducer, someService)
      },
      {
        authenticated: false
      })
  ],
  ...
```

I need that because I need to use a fully functional service (that depends on `Http`) from a plain function (named `someFunction` above) in order to rehydrate a **ngrx store** application.

Here `someFunction` is a meta reducer.

See concept of [meta reducer](https://gist.github.com/btroncone/a6e4347326749f938510#implementing-a-meta-reducer)  in ngrx store application.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not completely sure I understand what you are trying to do (without seeing more code), but I imagine what you are trying to do can be done by using a factory for the provider configuration

```
providers: [
  {
    provide: WhateverService,
    useFactory: (things: Things, to: To, inject: Inject) => {
      // Not 100% sure, but I believe the return should be 
      // synchronous. If you have some asynchronous actions
      // to be resolved first, you may just want to pass the 
      // Promise or Observable to the constructor
      return new WhateverService(...);
    },
    deps: [Things, To, Inject]
  }
]
```

In your `StoreModule`, it could be something like

```
@NgModule({})
export class StoreModule {
  static provideStore(variable) {
    return {
      ngModule: StoreModule,
      providers: [
        {
          provide: WhateverService,
          useFactory: (things: Things, to: To, inject: Inject) => {
            // use variable here
            return new WhateverService(...);
          },
          deps: [Things, To, Inject]
        }
      ]
    }    
  }
}
```

Another option, if you are trying to resolve some remote data before bootstrap, is to do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39454713/2587435). Other than that, I may be completely off, as I am not familiar with ngrx.

Comment: I used the sample from the linked reply http://stackoverflow.com/a/39454713/536299. Thanks a lot.