# Angular 2: Multiple layout files using interpolation

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template

I'm building an Angular 2 app and need two layout files. One for the logged out users... (Login/Register views etc) and one for the logged in users to see the actual app itself. How can this be achieved with Angular 2?

Currently I have an `app.component.html` that simply has

```
<main-navbar></main-navbar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

But what I need to do is something along the lines of:

```
<div [ngSwitch]="layout">

  <template [ngSwitchCase]="panelLayout">
      /* output all the html layout elements for the logged out views */
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  <template>

  <template [ngSwitchCase]="appLayout">
     /* output all the html elements for the in logged in/app views */
     <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </template>

</div>
```

But I have no idea where or how to set the `layout` variable.

I'm presuming this variable would best be set inside the main view component... or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You can try this [Multiple layout in angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38780436/how-to-switch-layouts-in-angular2/38783451#38783451). Hope it helps. Been using it for a while now and it scales very well no matter the number of layout your would want to use in your app

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to switch layouts in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38780436/how-to-switch-layouts-in-angular2)

Answer (score 2):

I worked out what I was trying to achieve by using transclusion... as far as I can see this isn't mentioned anywhere in the official docs!

It's simply a case of using `<ng-content></ng-content>` in the layout files where the main content for each layout needs to go.

```
// eg: app-layout.html
<app-header></app-header>
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
// content using this layout will appear below
<ng-content></ng-content>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

Then after importing and including in directives use the layout it in a view like

```
// eg: dashboard.html
<app-layout>
  <h1>Hello {{user}}!</h1>
</app-layout>
```

Hope this helps someone trying to achieve the same thing

Comment: Man sorry but this is totally not clear to understand. The example feels unfinished.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to switch your view with different routes, i.e., one route for the logged in users that resolves to a `component A` and another route for users that aren't logged in that resolves to a `component B`.

I prefer to use this strategy because you can block users in the route level using the `CanActivate` hook, i.e., before going to a particular route, there's a validation. If it's false, the user won't access that route. If it's true, the route is activated.

You can read the awesome documentation about how to use the `CanActivate` here in the [Routing & Navigation: CanActivate Guard](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#can-activate-guard) documentation.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm already using the CanActivate guard method to redirect users to the `/login` route if not logged in but I want to know how to create reusable layout files that are used for multiple routes depending on which route/view component is active.

Comment: If I've got the point, do you want to use the same html file with different components that are shown in different routes?

Comment: Yes, that's right. So the "logged out" layout would simply show a logo and then the nested route view of either a login form or registration form and the "logged in/app" layout would have the main app navigation and then show the content of each app route inside of that... hope that makes sense?

Comment: In my opinion is better to separate the concerns, i. e., create a component and a route to deal with the sign in and register process and another component and route to deal with the logged in app. And here we use what I suggested about the can activate guard that you said you're using. This guard is only used in the authenticated routes. Separating in this way is much easier to maintain a large application.

Comment: Ok, I get what you're saying now I think... so there are two main components and each would have nested routes... right?

Comment: A proposal could be: route `/signin` mapped to a `SignInComponent`, route `/register` mapped to a `RegisterComponent` and route `/` with a `CanActivate` guard mapped to a `DashboardComponent`. If an unauthorized user tries to access the `/` route, the `CanActivate` guard redirect to the `/signin` route.

Answer (score 0):

Just inject a shared service that provides the current `loggedIn` status to the component.

```
@Injectable()
class AuthService {
  isLoggedIn = new BehaviorSubject(false);

  ...      
}
```

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [..., AuthService]);
```

```
@Component({
  template: `
<div [ngSwitch]="authService.isLoggedIn | async">

  <template [ngSwitchCase]="false">
      /* output all the html layout elements for the logged out views */
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  <template>

  <template [ngSwitchCase]="false">
     /* output all the html elements for the in logged in/app views */
     <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </template>

</div>
`
})
class MyComponent {
  constructor(private authService:AuthService) {};
}
```

See also [Make AJAX request before bootstrapping Angular2 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38707076/make-ajax-request-before-bootstrapping-angular2-application)

Comment: I appreciate your answer and that would certainly work but for the size of app I'm building using the <ng-content> transclusion in seperate layout files as described above is my preferred solution as it keeps things seperate and tidy and using a guard to protect routes.

Comment: Is this the best approuch to handle multiple layouts in angular 2? Like a login page with a simple layout and the other pages with other layout

Comment: You can use the router to show various views. This is just to dispay a single component in various ways.

Comment: In my app.component I've got this <header-component><header-component><router-outlet></router-outlet> when I navigate to login I want to get rid of the <header-component> but for all other pages when the user is logged in I just want to display the layout as it is. Do I have to use ng-if with a service to archieve this? What's the best way? Do you have a link or something to help me I've stucked on this for days.

Comment: `*ngIf` and a service sounds right for this use case